# Need to run file located in cgi-bin using CGI

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cgi, fastcgi

I usually use hosts for mounting sites and they come with CGI working.

```
Server API  CGI/FastCGI
```

Now I mounted a site in an AWS EC2 instance using ubuntu 14.04 and apache 2.4 Followed some tutorials to install FastCGI and now I have this configuration in my php info:

```
Server API  FPM/FastCGI
```

When I try to access to the /var/www/html/cgi-bin directory I find the files, changed all permissions to try to execute them but I get this error:

```
[cgi:error] [pid 5951:tid 140061935601408] [client 186.67.242.72:22739] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/test.cgi
```

The file I'm trying to excecute is located in /var/www/html/cgi-bin/test.php

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use CGI;
print "content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "Prueba CGI!\n";
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The log message holds the answer:

> script not found or unable to stat: **/usr/lib/cgi-bin**/test.cgi

If you check your Apache config you should notice a `ScriptAlias` for `/cgi-bin` to `/usr/lib/cgi-bin`. You can solve this by:

1. Place your cgi scripts in `/usr/lib/cgi-bin`
2. Change the `ScriptAlias` to `/var/www/html/cgi-bin` and restart Apache
3. Set the cgi option and handlers for the cgi-bin directory in the `/var/www/html` virtual host and restarting Apache